# How to write files with Unix end of lines on R for Windows

Tags: r

I have an R script that creates a text file on Windows.

I use both `write.table` and `write` functions to write to the file.

I then need to use this file on Unix systems, but the file has Windows end of line characters (^M).

Is it possible to write files with R on Windows that have Unix end of line characters?

## Edit

Here is a reproducible example:

```
output.file <- file.path("./test.txt")

x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(5,6,7,8)
my.df <- data.frame(x, y)
my.df[] <- lapply(my.df, sprintf, fmt = "%14.7E")

write("First line", file = output.file)
write("Second line", file = output.file, append = TRUE)
write.table(my.df,
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            file = output.file,
            quote = FALSE,
            append = TRUE,
            sep = "")
```

And the result, as seen by NotePad++:

[image]

Comment: See the `eol` argument for `write.table`

Comment: By default eol argument is set to \n, so it should already work. Moreover, I use both write() and write.table() functions. There is no eol parameter in write, I add \n manually. Still got the ^M when reading with Unix

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As stated in `help(write.table)`:

> To write a Unix-style file on Windows, use a binary connection e.g.
>   file = file("filename", "wb").

In your example, just change first line to open a `"wb"` connection and `close` file at the end:

```
output.file <- file("./test.txt", "wb")

x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(5,6,7,8)
my.df <- data.frame(x, y)
my.df[] <- lapply(my.df, sprintf, fmt = "%14.7E")

write("First line", file = output.file)
write("Second line", file = output.file, append = TRUE)
write.table(my.df,
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            file = output.file,
            quote = FALSE,
            append = TRUE,
            sep = "")

close(output.file)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

unix type line endings can be achieved by using `wb` write|binary mode in file connections.

This quote from Rnews article may be helpful:
[Ripley, B. D. (2001) Connections. R News, 1/1, 16–7.](https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-1.pdf)

> **Text vs binary** There is a distinction between text mode and binary mode connections. The intention is that text-based functions like scan
>   and cat should use text mode connections, and binary mode is used with
>   readBin and writeBin. This distinction is not yet consistently
>   enforced, and the main underlying difference is whether files are
>   opened in text or binary mode (where that matters). It now looks as if
>   opening all files in binary mode and managing the translation of line
>   endings internally in R will lead to fewer surprises. Already reading
>   from a connection in text mode translates lines endings from Unix
>   (LF), DOS/Windows (CRLF) and Macintosh (CR) formats (and from all
>   connections, not just files).

```
# setup file connection
con <- file( output.file )

# open connection
if( !isOpen(con = con, rw = "wb") ) { open( con, open = "wb" ) }

# write contents
write( x = paste( colnames(my.df), collapse = "\t" ), file = con )
for( i in 1:nrow( my.df )){
  write(paste( my.df[i, ], collapse = "\t" ), file = con )
}
close( con )  # close and destroy a connection

# verify file contents
read.table(output.file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
#   x y
# 1 1 5
# 2 2 6
# 3 3 7
# 4 4 8
```