# How to convert ending line characters from Windows to Unix using R

Tags: r, windows, unix, character

I wonder how to convert ending line characters from Windows to Unix using R.

I saw in another post that it's possible using the `script write()`, but when I try that, it doesn't work(it returns an empty file). Instead, I'd like to use the `write.table()` command, if it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write files with Unix end of lines on R for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933590/how-to-write-files-with-unix-end-of-lines-on-r-for-windows)

Comment: The answers on the linked post use `write.table`.

Comment: I think that this one use output.file <- file("./test.txt", "wb") and write() option. I tried to adapt it to my case, but it doesn't work. Maybe because I didn't understed how to proper use that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write some text:

```
library(readr)
text <- c("line one", "line two")

write_lines(text, file = "text.linux.txt", sep = "\n")
write_lines(text, file = "text.macos.txt", sep = "\r")
write_lines(text, file = "text.windows.txt", sep = "\r\n")
```

There are similar options e.g. `eol` in `write.table` and `write_csv` to set the end of line characters.

Comment: It works, but it gives to me an output file full of " and with a different way to queue my data. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Also, I tried to use eol = "\n", but my output file still has ending line character for windows

Comment: What do you mean with 'full of "?' How did you check the line ending of the produced file?

Comment: for example, my output is something like this: c("G", "C", "T", "A", "A", "G", "C"... and it's supposed to give me something like this: G C T A A G C.
I use notepad++ to see the line ending (and I know I can change it using this editor, but I wish to use R).